# Any good references for python and C code mixing?

Tags: python, c

I've been looking at docs but I can't seem to understand very clearly, them do you guys know of anything that would be good at teaching it.

Say I had a program,

```
int main() {
   return 3;
}
```

How do I call cprogram.exe and get the return value (not neccesarily an int, structs too). I don't have a specific project that I'm working on, just trying to learn. So on top of answering this question, some references (books or otherwise) to where I could learn continuation of this, because I know its more complicated than this; would be nice; thanks in advance.

lol sentence structure.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of doing this would be to create a dll or so (depending on your platform) then use the ctypes module to call into it. The exact method for creating the dll depends on your compiler. For ctypes see [python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180404121539/python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Wesley Chun has a nice chapter showing how to do it in his "Core Python Programming" book.

Answer (score 0):

The Python docs themselves may be a good place to start:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ext/intro.html